# Oracle Nested Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to pull a field in the top nested query without having to pull the same field in the below subqueries? For example, Date field was not pulled in Level 2, but I need it in Level 3. I am just trying to avoid creating any extra views or tables just to store Level 2 data.

```
SELECT PART, SUM_QTY, DATE1, DATE2 FROM                            - Level 3

(
SELECT PART,SUM(QTY) AS SUM_QTY FROM                               - Level 2

(
SELECT PART,QTY,DATE1 FROM TABLE1                                  - Level 1

LEFT JOIN

SELECT PART,QTY,DATE2 FROM TABLE2

)
GROUP BY PART

)
GROUP BY PART,DATE
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Query you wrote is invalid (left join won't work that way).

Anyway, you could use a CTE (Common Table Expression) a.k.a. the WITH factoring clause. For example:

```
with 
level1 as
  (select a.part, a.qty, a.date1, b.date2
   from table1 a join table2b on a.part = b.part
  ),
level2 as
  (select l1.part, 
          sum(l2.qty) sum_qty
   from level1 l1
   group by l1.part
  )
-- level3
select l2.part, l2.sum_qty, l1.date1, l1.date2
from level2 l2 join level1 l1 on l2.part = l1.part
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `UNION` instead of `LEFT JOIN` then use window function `SUM()OVER()` for getting `SUM_QTY`.

```
SELECT PART,
         SUM_QTY,
         DATE1,
         DATE2
    FROM (SELECT PART,
                 SUM (QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY PART) AS SUM_QTY,
                 DATE1,
                 DATE2
            FROM (SELECT PART,
                         QTY,
                         DATE1,
                         NULL DATE2
                    FROM TABLE1
                  UNION
                  SELECT PART,
                         QTY,
                         NULL DATE1,
                         DATE2
                    FROM TABLE2)--          GROUP BY PART
         )
GROUP BY PART,
         DATE1,
         DATE2,
         SUM_QTY
```